# How do would I register this in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

```
public interface IDo
{
    ... details 
}
public class DoOneThing : IDo
{
    ...
}
public class DoAnotherThing : IDo
{
    ....
}

public interface IFooService
{
    ... details
}

public class FooService
{
    private IDo do;

    public FooService(IDo do)
    {
        // instance is of type specifically resolved per call
        this.do = do;
    }


    ...
}

Container.Register(ComponentFor<IDo>().ImplementedBy<DoOneThing>().Named("DoOneThing");
Container.Register(ComponentFor<IFooService>().ImplementedBy<FooService>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IDo), "DoOneThing")).Named("DoItWithOneThing");
Container.Register(ComponentFor<IFooService>().ImplementedBy<FooService>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IDo), "DoAnotherThing")).Named("DoItWithAnotherThing");



Container.Resolve<IFooService>("DoItWithOneThing");
```

How Do I register FooService to have a dependency of type IDo and then resolve with a specific implementation type? I've tried using something like the code above but I get an exception that no component for service can be found. If I try to resolve to the named instance then it tells me that it's waiting for dependencies of DoOneThing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the typed `Dependency.OnComponent` as mentioned in [Castle Windsor - multiple implementation of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18028790/580951).

See also: [Castle Project -- Inline dependencies](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx)

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IDo>()
        .ImplementedBy<DoAnotherThing>());

container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IDo>()
        .ImplementedBy<DoOneThing>());

container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IFooService>()
        .ImplementedBy<FooService>()
        .Named("DoItWithOneThing")
        .DependsOn(
            Dependency.OnComponent<IDo, DoOneThing>()));

container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IFooService>()
        .ImplementedBy<FooService>()
        .Named("DoItWithAnotherThing")
        .DependsOn(
            Dependency.OnComponent<IDo, DoAnotherThing>()));
```

Test

```
var doItWithOneThing = container.Resolve<IFooService>("DoItWithOneThing");
var doItWithAnotherThing = container.Resolve<IFooService>("DoItWithAnotherThing");

Console
    .WriteLine(
        "doItWithOneThing.Do is DoOneThing // {0}",
        doItWithOneThing.Do is DoOneThing);
Console
    .WriteLine(
        "doItWithAnotherThing.Do is DoAnotherThing // {0}",
        doItWithAnotherThing.Do is DoAnotherThing);
```

Output

```
doItWithOneThing.Do is DoOneThing // True
doItWithAnotherThing.Do is DoAnotherThing // True
```

Declarations

```
public interface IDo {}
public class DoOneThing : IDo {}
public class DoAnotherThing : IDo {}
public interface IFooService
{
    IDo Do { get; }
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public FooService(IDo @do)
    {
        Do = @do;
    }

    public IDo Do { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I get 'DoItWithOneThing' is waiting for the following dependencies: - Component 'DoOneThing' (via override) which was not found.' even though I registered DoOneThing before IFooService.

Comment: I missed removing the Named from the IDo registration. It works now. Thanks for your help