# Resolving correct dependency when interface is shared

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have an application with a "Data processing layer". One of the classes have a dependency on two data repositories - each implementing a `IDataRepository´-interface.

The class looks like somewhat like this:

```
public class ProcessingLayer
{
  public ProcessingLayer(IDataRepository employeeRepository, IDataRepository organizationRepository)
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

As I am hoping is obvious, I need those two repos to get data from two sources.

Before I found out I needed an additional repo, my dependency creation looked like this:

```
   var container = new WindsorContainer();
   container
    .Register(
      Component.For<IDataRepository>()
        .ImplementedBy<EmployeeRepository>()
        .LifestyleTransient()
      );
```

My question is: how do I make two registrations with the same interface and still enabling Castle.Windsor to figure out which to assign to which parameter in the ctor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor - multiple implementation of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008547/castle-windsor-multiple-implementation-of-an-interface)

Comment: A common solution doesn't involve the tool per se, but a change in approach, that is avoiding duplicated abstractions service different purposes. Or in more plain language - avoiding duplicate `IDataRepository` and having `IDataRepository<Employee>` and `IDataRepository<Organization>` or `EmployeeRepository` and `OrganizationRepository` as separate clear abstractions. That way the intent is clear, and, as a side-effect, the tooling also _just works_.

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic the generic repository approach is a really good idea - I will try that out. Thank you :-)